# what is the good way to display images after successfully uploading to server, objective-c,ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, core-data

Given  :

1. view A ( uitableView ) is used to display all images after you successfully pull them from a server via a request named *getAllImages*
2. you can also upload a new photo in view A via a top right button

My Goal :

- Display a new set of images ( the new images included) on the table

What I am doing is :

1. send the request to server for uploading image ( i am using afnetworking to do that)
2. since server side is only returned "success" or failure" to me without other information. Supposed it is success, I will fire a request to get the new set of images via *getAllImages*
3. will invoke *reloadData* to display a new set of data on the table

I am not sure this is a good way to do it, I am still looking for the best approach to achieve this task. I dont know should I use core data in this task and how to use it.

Please give me any suggestions if you have been experiencing this task. Any comments are appreciated.

Comment: Do you have control of the server side api? if you dont , and all that is available to you is getAllImages, then your only other choice is instead of displaying the image from the server when its "added" to just display it with the local file, until a refresh is done..

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I would do:

1 - call getAllImages to show all N images

2 - take new photo

3 - display N images previously gotten from getAllImages, and 1 local image from step 2

4 - fire asynchronous request (do not specifically remember how do we do that using  AFNetworking)  to upload image from step 2

5 - if success code, keep N+1 images. If failure code, show only N images and remove the last one.

You can specifically reload only single row using reloadrowatindexpath, without much of a performance hit.